# NGXS 3.1.4 Store calculations/operations

Tags: angular, angular6, ngxs

I am building an Angular 6 app and trying to understand NGXS (3.1.4).

I have already managed to implement @Actions to ADD and REMOVE Cart Items from/to the store; those actually work.

I am still trying to do the following:

1. Count the total number of cartItems and display that as a value in
   an angular html component
2. Clear all cartItems in the Cart

**SOLVED**

```
@Action(EmptyCart) emptyCart(ctx: StateContext<CartStateModel>, action: EmptyCart) { 
const state = ctx.getState(); 
const current = { cartItems: [] }; 
ctx.setState({ ...state, ...current }); 
}
```

3. Update just the quantity of a CartItem in cartItems if the id already exists
4. Calculate the total amount of the Cart by calculating each cartItems price * quantity and adding that to a running total to display in an angular html component

I appreciate that I am asking multiple questions, but they are related to the same issue.

If there is a video or link that covers this kind of problem that would be great.  I have attempted google/youtube searches and looking at the github docs for NGXS.

Below is what I am using:

```
export interface CartItem {
  tempID: number;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;

}

export class CartStateModel {
    cartItems: CartItem[];
}

@State<CartStateModel>({
  name: 'cartItems',
  defaults: {
    cartItems: []
  }
})
```

Thanks for any feedback :-)

Comment: https://github.com/chybie/ngxs-coffee/blob/master/src/app/state/app.state.ts looks like it may solve some of the issues I am trying to solve!

Comment: @Action(EmptyCart)
  emptyCart(ctx: StateContext<CartStateModel>, action: EmptyCart) {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    const current = { cartItems: [] };
    ctx.setState({
      ...state,
      ...current
    });
  }

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach I'm using:

```
function emptyCartState() {
  return {
    cartItems: [],
  }
}

@State<CartStateModel>({
  name: 'cartItems',
  defaults: emptyCartState(),
})

..
..
..
Action(EmptyCart)
emptyCart(ctx: StateContext<CartStateModel>, action: EmptyCart) { 
  return of(ctx.setState(emptyCartState()));
}
```